# Pass multiple variables from javascript function to controller function with window.location.href codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter-3

I have a function in my controller that will take two parameters , these parameters are beeing sent by a javascript function.

```
function seance(id)
{
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10) {
        dd='0'+dd;
    }    

    if(mm<10) {
        mm='0'+mm;
    } 

    var today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy; 

    window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('index.php/seance/liste_seance/')?>/" + id + "/" + today;
}
```

but only the first variable is sent correctly!

How can I send these two parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you show us your controller.
But I see some problems in your JS.

You are usint `var today` in your js two times. Remove `var` on the line 16.

Your site url will be in this format: `http://example.com/index.php/seance/liste_seance//id/04/27/2017`. Remove slash `/` after liste_seance. And you should change your date format, because in your controller you are getting 4 parameters: **id**, **04**, **27** and **2017**.